# Collect bracket output as a variable

Tags: bash

I have a script like this

```
{
    echo ...
    echo ...
} | iconv --to-code UTF-16LE | base64 -w0
```

Is it possible to collect the output from the `{}`, as a variable?

I've tried minimal cases like this,

```
a={echo 123;}
```

But only getting a syntax error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```
a=$(
echo 123
echo 456
)
```

or

```
a=$(echo 123; echo 456)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a="$({ echo 1; echo 2; echo 3;})"
```

But the braces may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
$ {
    echo Hello
    echo World
} | { 
    read -d '' -a var ; 
    echo "${var[@]}"; 
}
Hello World
```

However, var will be undefined outside the second braces.